# Evaluating a limit of $xf(2)$ - $2f(x)/x-2$ as $x$ approaches $2$

Tags: limits, derivatives

I was doing exercises on limit and I came across this question:

find the limit of ( $xf(2)$ - $2f(x)$ ) $/$ ($x-2$) as $x$ approaches 2 given $f(2) = 7$ and $f'(2) = 5$.

so I proceeded this way:

as $ x $ approaches 2, $ xf(2) $ approaches $ 2f(2) $. Therefore,

$xf(2)$ - $2f(x)$  $/$ $x-2$ $ = $  $ 2f(2)$ - $2f(x)$  $/$ $x-2$

Factoring $2$ and since $ lim f(x) - f(a)/x-a $  is $f'(x)$

The limit evaluates to   $2f'(x)$

Is the way I proceeded the right way? How do you do similar questions like:

$ lim$ $ nf(x) - f(a)/x-a $

or

$ lim f(x) - nf(a)/x-a $

Comment: "as $ x $ approaches 0, $ xf(2) $ approaches $ 2f(2) $." -- Pretty sure it doesn't? First there's no $f(2)$ in the limit. Secondly, as $x \to 0$, $x f(x) \to 0 \cdot f(0)$ (and in turn $0$), provided $f$ is "nice enough" anyhow. I feel like there's typos somewhere.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici sorry, it is $f'(2) = 5$

Comment: Are you 100% certain that you have $$x f(x) - 2 f(x)$$ in the numerator? This contradicts your idea for a generalization at the end of your post, and your working thus far.

Comment: @EeveeTrainer there were many typos, i have corrected them, Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just rewrite it as follows

$$\frac{xf(2) - 2f(x)}{x-2}= \frac{xf(2) - 2f(2) + 2f(2) - 2f(x)}{x-2}$$ 
$$= f(2)-2\frac{ f(x) - f(2)}{x-2}\stackrel{x\to 2}{\rightarrow} = 7-2\cdot 5 = -3$$

The idea behind it is to rewrite the expression in a form such that you can use the two given facts

- $f(2) = 7$ and
- $f'(2) = \lim_{x \to 2}\frac{f(x)-f(2)}{x-2} = 5$

Now, one looks how one can "rediscover" these two facts in the given expression. A possible way I have given above.

Answer (score 1):

The title says $x \to 2$ but you have changed it to $x \to 0$ in the question. It is more likely that you are asked to find the limit as $ x\to 2$. If you approximate only the numerator you are not approximating the ratio. So your first step is not valid. Apply L'Hopital's Rule to the get the limit as $\lim_{x\to 2} \frac {xf'(x)+f(x)-2f'(x)} {1}=2f'(2)+f(2)-2f'(2)=f(2)=7$.

$\lim_{x \to a} \frac {nf(x)-f(a)} {x-a}=0$ if $nf(a)\neq f(a)$. It is $nf'(a)$ if $nf(a)=f(a)$.

Comment: I fell for this trap too but note that the OP states the limit as $x \to 0$, not $2$.

Comment: @EeveeTrainer Thanks for the comment. But it is doubtful if OP copied the question correctly since the title conflicts with the question.

Comment: Yeah I'm inclined to agree. I also agree with your conclusion that given the information they gave it's more likely - in whatever way you wish interpret that - that they meant to find the limit at $2$.

Comment: And based on the most recent edit, seems like it is so. Oh well.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy is there any other way to do it without using L'Hopital's Rule?

Comment: You can use the fact that $f(x)=f(2)+(x-2)f'(2)+o((x-2))$